# Angular ngStyle for multiple styles

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on a simple [animation library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-load-animation) where my user can modify my component using property binding, so far I have been doing the following to apply their choices:

```
<div [style.background]="color" [style.width.px]="width" [style.height.px]="height"></div>
```

But for future additions I wish to change this whole mess with `[ngStyle]="styleObject"` to simplify adding more properties, I am trying to achieve this like such:

```
@Input() width: number;
@Input() height: number;

public styleObject: Object = {
    'height': this.height,
    'width': this.width
};
```

But for some reason `<div [ngStyle]="styleObject"></div>` is not taking into account the style shown above.

Please note that adding `+ 'px'` and doing `height.px` does not solve my issue.

What am I not seeing?

--

A few tests have shown that

```
styleObject = {
    'height': 200 + 'px',
    'background': 'red'
};
```

works and is applied to the `div`, but that replacing `200` with `this.height` (of type `number`) does not.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

When you using `ngStyle` you should create a function returning one of the following: a string, an array or an object.

if you want to return an Object you do the following:

in your template:

```
<div [ngStyle]="styleObject()"></div>
```

in your component:

```
export class AppComponent{
 styleObject(): Object {
       if (/** YOUR CONDITION TO SHOW THE STYLES*/  ){
           return {height: this.height,width: this.width}
       }
       return {}
   }
}
```

Comment: @Chris your You're welcome Chris! I am glad this helped you :)

Comment: WaleykumusSalaam. Thanks Hamed. This helped me in Angular 5.

Comment: Though this "works" please do not use functions in binding statements.  More info here: https://dzone.com/articles/why-we-shound-not-use-function-inside-angular-temp

Answer (score 46):

Try this approach

```
[ngStyle]="isTrue ? {width: '50px', height: '20px'} : {}"
```

Or

```
[ngStyle]="{
  width: '50px', 
  height: '20px'
}"
```

Comment: [ngStyle] is triggered multiple times, by any click on the page or app and this lead to performance issues.

Comment: I tried with Angular 14 and need to add ' like {'width': '50px', 'height': '20px'}

Answer (score 14):

You can enumerate multiple style rules like this inside `ngStyle`:

```
<img src="..." [ngStyle]="{'height' : size+'px', 'width' : size+'px'}" />
```

Answer (score 2):

I think Angular has started supporting unit. Working on `Angular: 8.2.14`.

> The key is a style name, with an optional . suffix (such as 'top.px', 'font-style.em').

Now you can use
`[ngStyle]="{'width.px':200, 'height.px':200}"`

Answer (score 0):

If you define your `styleObject` like that `this.height` and `this.width` will be undefined. At the very least, define the `styleObject` in `ngOnInit` in which bindings will be guaranteed to be initialized.

For a more dynamic feel, where the user can change properties after the component has been rendered, you can use getters/setters.

It will look something like this:

```
export class YourComponent {    
  styleObject: {[key: string]: string} = {};

  @Input()
  set width(w: string) {
    styleObject = Object.assign({}, styleObject, {width: w});
  }
  get width() { return styleObject.width; }

  @Input()
  set height(h: string) {
    styleObject = Object.assign({}, styleObject, {height: h});
  }
  get height() { return styleObject.height; }
}
```

You can probably omit the getters, actually.

Comment: How can the user access these setters? Programmatically?

Comment: The setters are called from the template. For example:

<your-component [width]="width" />

will call the width setter whenever width changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach `[ngStyle]="{ backgroundColor: 'blue':'transparent', color: 'white'}"`

Answer (score 0):

The code below shows how to do multiple styles:

```
[ngStyle]="{'left' : calcWidth,'top' : calcHeight}"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to add different conditions for different styling, you can do in this way:

```
 [ngStyle]="{
  'background-color': rank >= 3 ? '#1371FE' : '#E8E8E8',
  'color': rank == 1 ?'white':'#1A1B1C'
}"
```